# how to update many to many relationship tags in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i just have made a new app in laravel. i am trying to update my blog posts with tags. here is my form.

```
    {{ Form::model($blog, array('route' => array('admin.blog.update', $blog->slug), 'method' => 'PUT', 'files' => true)) }} <!-- text input -->
                   <div class="form-group">
                     {!! Form::label('title', 'Title') !!}
                     {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title']) !!}
                   </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      {!! Form::label('description', 'Please Type Here Content') !!}
                      {!! Form::textarea('content', null, ['class'=>'ckeditor', 'id'=>'my-editor']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Category</label>
                      <select name="tag[]" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select Categories"
                              style="width: 100%;">
                        @forelse($tags as $tag)
                        <option>{{ $tag->name }}</option>
                        @empty
                        @endforelse
                      </select>
                    </div>
                   <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('published_at', 'Publish On') !!}
                        {!! Form::input('date', 'published_at', date('Y-m-d'), ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                      </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      {!! Form::label('image', 'Choose Image') !!}
                      {!! Form::file('image') !!}
                    </div>
                    @push('scripts')
                <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
                <script>
                  var options = {
                    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '{{ url('filemanager')}}?type=Images',
                    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '{{ url('upload')}}?type=Images&_token={{csrf_token()}}',
                    filebrowserBrowseUrl: '{{ url('filemanager')}}?type=Files',
                    filebrowserUploadUrl: '{{ url('upload')}}?type=Files&_token={{csrf_token()}}'
                  };
                  CKEDITOR.replace('my-editor', options);
                </script>
                <script>
  $(function () {
    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    $('.select2').select2()



    //Timepicker
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({
      showInputs: false
    })
  })
</script>
                @endpush
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                {!! Form::submit('Submit', array( 'class'=>'btn btn-info' )) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

here is my controller

```
> public function blogeditupdate($blog, Request $request){
>         $blog = Blog::where('slug', $blog)->firstorfail();$blog = new Blog;
>         $blog->title = $request->title;
>         $blog->content = $request->content;
>         $blog->slug = str_slug($blog->title, '-');
>         $blog->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
>         $blog->published_at = Carbon::now();
>         if($request->hasFile('image')) {
>             $file = Input::file('image');
>             //getting timestamp
>             $timestamp = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
>             $name = $timestamp. '-' .$file->getClientOriginalName();
>             $file->move(public_path().'/images/blog/', $name);
>             $blog->image = $name;
>             $thumb = Image::make(public_path().'/images/blog/' . $name)->resize(640,420)->save(public_path().'/images/blog/thumb/' .
> $name, 90);
>         }
>         $blog_id = $blog->id;
>         $tags = $request['tag'];
>         if (isset($tags)) {        
>             $blog->tags()->sync($tags);  //If one or more tags is selected associate blog to tagblog          
>         }        
>         else {
>             $blog->tags()->detach(); //If no tags is selected remove exisiting role associated to a blogs
>         }
>         return redirect()->route('admin.blog.index')->with('status', 'Edit Success');
>     }
```

here is my error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'blog_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `blog_tagblog` (`blog_id`, `created_at`, `tagblog_id`, `updated_at`) values (, 2017-09-10 15:17:11, ghanta, 2017-09-10 15:17:11)) ◀"

i am missing something but i don't know what i am doing wrong.please help me!!

Comment: go to phpmyadmin and set blog_id to null

Comment: is this column should be null

Comment: yes you can if there is no data coming for blog_id

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the very first line in your controller, you have this:

```
$blog = new Blog;
```

This means that `$blog` will not have an id, and when you attempt to set the relationship, the `blog_id` field will be `null`, which violates your integrity constraints.

If this line is a mistake, delete it.

If not, you need to call `$blog->save()` before you attempt to sync your tags.